# Why "cv2.imread" behaves differently for image files having different names?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, os.path, python

I am trying to write a python script which should take images as input and crop them and save the cropped images in a different folder with same (original) file name. So I wrote the following code ..

```
import cv2
#import numpy 
import os 
import glob
#import sys


for imgfile in glob.glob(r"C:\Users\mainu\Documents\ACADEMIC YEAR 20_21\Master thesis\Implementation\Applications\Apps_with_opencv\Test\*.jpg"):
    
    img= cv2.imread(imgfile)
    name = os.path.basename(imgfile) 
    print('old name :',name)
    rows,colmn,channel = img.shape # to know the shape of the image

    #cv2.imshow('This image has :' + str(rows) +' number of rows,' + str(colmn) +' number of columns',img) #shows the image
   
    #cv2.waitKey(0) #waits untill any key is pressed

    cropped_img = img[400:949,408:1588] # here we are cutting the image 
    #rows,colmn,channel = cropped_img.shape # to know the shape of the new image
    #cv2.imshow('This image has :' + str(rows) +' number of rows,' + str(colmn) +' number of columns',cropped_img) #shows the new image
    #cv2.waitKey(0) #waits untill any key is pressed
    
    filename = r"C:\Users\mainu\Documents\ACADEMIC YEAR 20_21\Master thesis\Implementation\Applications\Apps_with_opencv\Test_2/" + name
    name_2 = os.path.basename(filename)
    print('new name :',name_2)
    cv2.imwrite(filename,cropped_img)
```

Now the problem is it works fine until it gets file names like : tes_1.jpg ... but doesn't work for when the file name is longer one. Please have a look :

```
(Env_CV2) C:\Users\mainu\Documents\ACADEMIC YEAR 20_21\Master thesis\Implementation\Applications\Apps_with_opencv>"c:/Users/mainu/Documents/ACADEMIC YEAR 20_21/Master thesis/Implementation/Applications/Apps_with_opencv/Env_CV2/Scripts/python.exe" "c:/Users/mainu/Documents/ACADEMIC YEAR 20_21/Master thesis/Implementation/Applications/Apps_with_opencv/Crop_app.py"
old name : test_1.jpg
new name : test_1.jpg
old name : test_2.jpg
new name : test_2.jpg
old name : test_3.jpg
new name : test_3.jpg
old name : test_4.jpg
new name : test_4.jpg
old name : test_5.jpg
new name : test_5.jpg
old name : WebCam_RGB_Car_2_screws_out_#1_°0-03_24_21-10_45.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/mainu/Documents/ACADEMIC YEAR 20_21/Master thesis/Implementation/Applications/Apps_with_opencv/Crop_app.py", line 13, in <module>
    rows,colmn,channel = img.shape # to know the shape of the image
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

It would be kind if someone can explain me the reason ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the reason for the error. my image file name was containing character like '°' and also space. when i removed them it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing that your img variable is `None`. That means the line `cv2.imread(imgfile)` returned `None` for some file in your for loop.

The cv2.imread method returns `None` by default if the file argument you passed doesn't exist. It doesn't raise any error.
You may want to put a try-except OR if-else block there to handle the missing images.

Comment: Thank you .. yes what you said is true, `None` is returned when doesn't exists .. but the file definitely exists in that folder because you can see `old name` is printed but `cv2.imread(imgfile)` can not read it. therefore i want to know why ?